# Regular expression to replace only if it has numeric value before

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to write a regular expression to replace `x` and `X` values with an underscore `_` only if `x` and `X` are if it's surrounded with digits, or preceded or followed by digits.

For example:

```
OFE_PALLET_120X92 will be OFE_PALLET_120_92
OFX_PALLET_120X92 will be OFX_PALLET_120_92
```

This is my initial code:

```
sRegExInput = new RegExp('[xX]', 'g');
result =    result.replace(sRegExInput ,'_');
```

How to achieve that?

Comment: If you got your answer, please do not forget to click the checkmark, under the voting number :)

Comment: What about `OFE_PALLET_120X`? Replace or not? (to OP)

Comment: yes it will be replaced, if it's sorrunded with digits , or preceeded or followed by digits , then it should be replaced 
other example , BOX_12x6 , should be BOX 12_6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\\d` in a constructor:

```js
var result = 'OFE_PALLET_120X92 will be OFE_PALLET_120_92';
var sRegExInput = new RegExp('(\\d)x', 'gi');
result = result.replace(sRegExInput ,'$1_');
console.log(result);
```

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  x                        'x' or 'X' due to i flag
```

The `$1` refers to the captured substring.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex:

```js
"OFX_PALLET_120X92".replace(/(\d)x/ig, "$1_")
// "OFX_PALLET_120_92"
```

Essentially, it finds a number, captures it, then finds an `X`, and replaces it with the captured number (`$1`) and an underscore.

Comment: But this also replaces `X` that does not continue with numbers. Like `120XCCC` to `120_CCC`

Comment: OP said **preceded** by numbers, not **surrounded**.

Answer (score 1):

With the provided regular expression, I do match the pattern as:

1. Find one or more digits,
2. Followed by `x` or `X`
3. Followed by one or more digits.

Then in the replace statement, I use the `$1` to put in the replacement the first group of found digits, and the `$3` to put in the replacement the last group of found digits.

The `map` in the `entries` variable used just to simplify the code. This has nothing to do with the regex.

```js
var entries = [
    'OFE_PALLET_120X92',
    'OFX_PALLET_120X92'
];

var result = entries.map(
    function(entry) {
        return entry.replace(/(\d+)([xX])(\d+)/g ,'$1_$3');
    }
);

console.log(result);
```

Run the code snippet to test the output :)

Comment: how to write this expression in sRegExInput = new RegExp('[xX]', 'g');
format , i've tried sRegExInput = new RegExp('/(\d+)([xX])(\d+)' ,'$1_$3', 'g');
 but it didn't work

Comment: @osfar remove the first `/` from the regex _string_ that you are using. Regex literals are wraped with `/` characters, but not when given as a string using `new Regex`

Comment: @osfar, if you run the code I provided here it works. It doesn't make any difference the way I used `/(\d+)([xX])(\d+)/g` with the use of `new RegExp('(\d+)([xX])(\d+)', 'g')`. The only possible issue it could be a wrong provided data though.

Comment: becuase i'm running this js code in special environment , which has limited JS compiler , i'm only restricted to use regExp object , i know both convetion will do the exact job , however i've tried to use new RegExp('(\d+)([xX])(\d+)', 'g') in firefox browser console , and it didn't replace the x value in OFE_PALLET_120X92

Comment: @osfar then maybe it related to the restrictions of your environment.

Comment: but I've tried it in firefox console and it didn't work 
new RegExp('(\d+)([xX])(\d+)', 'g') , if this convention worked in browser console then it will work in the other environment